# determining modulus numbers on 0-based array

Tags: c#

I have an array where the index starts at 0.  I am attempting to determine how I find specific items in array.

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

I only want 2,6,10,14.  If it wasn't a 0-index array I could do a modulus%3 on the index and get what I want but I cannot figure out how to do it.

```
    string[] arr = new string[16];
    arr[0] = "data";
    arr[1] = "data";
    arr[2] = "data";
    arr[3] = "data";
    arr[4] = "data";
    arr[5] = "data";
    arr[6] = "data";
    arr[7] = "data";
    arr[8] = "data";
    arr[9] = "data";
    arr[10] = "data";
    arr[11] = "data";
    arr[12] = "data";
    arr[13] = "data";
    arr[14] = "data";
    arr[15] = "data";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

This of course doesn't work for me and I've tried manipulating 'i' but I just haven't had enough coffee yet today to get it to work.

Comment: Do you mean `% 4` or `& 3` by any chance? `%3` would give you (say) 2, 5, 8, 11...

Comment: Downvote because the author mentions they attempted to manipulate the counter but didn't post that code.  Plus the code won't even compile because of the two **;** on a single line

Comment: Fixed the typo and I didn't post that code since it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want

```
if(i % 4 == 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you want:

```
if (i % 4 == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Or equivalently (but less generally for other values)

```
if ((i & 3) == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
{
    if(i % 4 == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
    }
}
```